# Use iptables to set online time 1 hour per day

Tags: time, firewall, iptables, children, restriction

is there any chance to configure iptables in a way that it allow a machine to be online for lets say one hour per day ? The time module can do this only in a way like "from ... until ..." but I need a more flexible solution. 
The machine could be online 30 minutes in the morning and then again 30 minutes in the evening but I dont find any way. Do I realy have to write a script for that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need a way of detecting when the machine is online and when it goes offline. A machine is not always continuously present, so there needs to be some buffer to account for an online *session* of the machine.

I take it that the machine you want to limit is not the machine on which you want to install the iptables rule? In that case, you need to detect the *session* (by inspecting logs on the monitor machine?) and continuously (every minute, using cron?) check whether the client machine has surpassed its allotted time.

Comment: You're right ... the firewall is a standalone machine. While reading your anwser I thought about using a vpn connection from the client to the firewall. I could count the time by cron but I know my son. He just forgets to terminate the connection and time is ticking away.

Comment: Apparently `iptables` allows a logging rule as well. In the example from the Ubuntu wiki for Iptables: `sudo iptables -I INPUT 5 -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7`. You could set the log limit for connections to 1 per minute and log timestamps. Then it's a matter of counting the lines in the log file, for a given day (you could say that a single request is _worth_ a minute). Depending on the result, (dis)able the connection for the machine. Seems to be an easy way of going about it, not too much effort.